# How Can I Get a Subset of an Object's Properties as a Python Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Short Version:**

In Python is there a way to (cleanly/elegantly) say "Give me these 5 (or however many) properties of an object, and nothing else, as a dictionary"?

**Longer Version:**

Using the Javascript Underscore library, I can reduce an bunch of objects/dictionaries (in JS they're the same thing) to a bunch of subsets of their properties like so:

```
var subsets = _(someObjects).map(function(someObject) {
    _(someObject).pick(['a', 'd']);
});
```

If I want to do the same thing with a Python object (not a dictionary) however it seems like the best I can do is use a list comprehension and manually set each property:

```
subsets = [{"a": x.a, "d": x.d} for x in someObjects]
```

That doesn't look so bad when there's only two properties, and they're both one letter, but it gets uglier fast if I start having more/longer properties (plus I feel wrong whenever I write a multi-line list comprehension).  I could turn the whole thing in to a function that uses a for loop, but before I do that, is there any cool built-in Python utility thing that I can use to do this as cleanly (or even more cleanly) than the JS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done simply by combining [a list comprehension with a dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

```
subsets = [{attr: getattr(x, attr) for attr in ["a", "d"]} 
           for x in someObjects]
```

Naturally, you could distill out that comprehension if you wanted to:

```
def pick(*attrs):
    return {attr: getattr(x, attr) for attr in attrs} 

subsets = [pick("a", "d") for x in someObjects]
```

Comment: Mah. I don't understand why they didn't implement a builtin version of this. Especially in cases in which this operation is repeated numerously, it feels cumbersome to keep writing frankly unnecessary comprehensions all over the code as well as annoying writing a dedicated 1-2 line(s) function just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = ['a', 'c']
>>> O = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 33, 'd': 44}]

>>> [{a: o[a] for a in A} for o in O]
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'c': 33}]

>>> list(map(lambda o: {a: o[a] for a in A}, O))
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 11, 'c': 33}]
```